# Instance of SQL Server running on Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, powershell, azure-devops, database-backups

I am trying to create a backup policy for databases on Azure as PAAS service of SQL server. The thing which came to my mind is to use PowerShell to take backup of databases inside SQL Server and then upload it azure storage account, the PowerShell will run on Azure Devops inside Microsoft hosted agents.

But I am confused on most of the points like:

1. How to get instance of that SQL server?
2. How generate new SQL credentials for this task since it it depends on task I stated above?

Please give your valuable suggestions.

Comment: have you seen the documentation ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/automated-backups-overview?tabs=single-database. you dont really need to do everything manually

Comment: Is there some part of the existing automatic backup features that does not meet your need? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/automated-backups-overview?tabs=single-database

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link I have gone through the link, earlier. Actually, it is a requirement of business as they phased some issue perhaps it was something like resource group got deleted or something.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use Azure Automation and Runbook for this type of thing. [Here](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Backup-SQLAzureDb/0.2.0/Content/Backup-SQLAzureDb.ps1) you have an example of RunBook to perform backup.

```
param(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String] $AutomationConnection,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String] $SubscriptionName,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]$StorageAccount,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]$BlobContainer,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]$StorageKey,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]$StorageKeytype = "StorageAccessKey",
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]$DbName,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]$ResourceGroupName,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]$ServerName,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]$serverAdmin,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]$ServerPassword
)

$VERSION = "0.2.0"
$currentTime = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()

Write-Output "Backup SQL Azure db automation script - version $VERSION"
Write-Output "Runbook started..."

# Main runbook content
try
{
    $securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $serverPassword -AsPlainText -Force
    $creds = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $serverAdmin, $securePassword

    # Generate a unique filename for the BACPAC
    $bacpacFilename = $ServerName + '-' + $DbName + '-' +(Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ") + ".bacpac"

    # Storage account info for the BACPAC
    $BaseStorageUri = "https://$storageAccount.blob.core.windows.net/$blobContainer/"
    $BacpacUri = $BaseStorageUri + $bacpacFilename


    Write-Output "Logging in to Azure..."
    # Get the connection
    $con = Get-AutomationConnection -Name $AutomationConnection
    $null = Add-AzureRmAccount -ServicePrincipal -TenantId $con.TenantId -ApplicationId $con.ApplicationId -CertificateThumbprint $con.CertificateThumbprint
    $null = Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName $SubscriptionName

    Write-Output "Will backup db $DbName to $blobContainer blob storage in storage account $storageAccount with name $bacpacFilename ..."
    $exportRequest = New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseExport -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ServerName $ServerName `
       -DatabaseName $DbName -StorageKeytype $StorageKeytype -StorageKey $StorageKey -StorageUri $BacpacUri `
       -AdministratorLogin $creds.UserName -AdministratorLoginPassword $creds.Password

    # Check status of the export
    $status = Get-AzureRmSqlDatabaseImportExportStatus -OperationStatusLink $exportRequest.OperationStatusLink

    Write-Output "Export status is:"
    $status
}
catch
{
    if (!$con)
    {
        $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
        throw $ErrorMessage
    } else{
        Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
        throw $_.Exception
    }
}
finally
{
    "Runbook finished (Duration: $(("{0:hh\:mm\:ss}" -f ((Get-Date).ToUniversalTime() - $currentTime))))"
}
```

And [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/learn/automation-tutorial-runbook-textual-powershell) is a tutorial for creating a RunBook in PowerShell. With this you can set a schedule and easily extend for as many databases as you need.

Another option and the best IMO are built-in features for backups on Azure SQL. Please take a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/automated-backups-overview?tabs=single-database)

Comment: Thanks for sharing but I got below error while running the runbook

_**New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseExport : The term 'New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseExport' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, 
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the**_

Comment: It could be an issue with rm modules. Probably they should be replaced with az modules.